# Make some columns not editable with Mindmup editable table

Tags: javascript

I am using [Mindmup editable tables](https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table).

I would like that the last column to not be editable (because in my case, it is a button to remove the row).

Can I do that with this library ?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no support for this feature.

But a quick fix is the following (based on [this issue](https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table/issues/6)):

Change the line 113 of the plugin from this:

```
element.find('td').prop('tabindex', 1);
```

To this:

```
element.find('td[data-editable!="false"]').prop('tabindex', 1);
```

And in your table, make the appropriate columns not editable like this:

```
<tr data-id=123">

  <td data-colname="first_name"
  >Chuck</td>

  <td data-colname="last_name"
  >Norris</td>

  <td data-editable="false"> <!-- data-editable added here -->
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      <i class="ti-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove
    </button>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Note: the weird formatting of the `td` tags is intentional: this way, the editable plugging doesn't insert white spaces while editing a cell.

Answer (score 1):

Update line 92 in mindmup-editabletable.js to:

```js
 $('.someClass').on('click keypress dblclick focus', showEditor)
```

Update line 114 in mindmup-editabletable.js to:

```js
element.find('.someClass').prop('tabindex', 1);
```

Now apply class="someClass" to each of the  elements that you want to be able to edit in your table.

Also, to remove the white space in the table cells, you can modify line 18 of the mindmup-editabletable.js to be:

```js
                    editor.val(active.text().trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the line 16 (in the showEditor function):

```
active = element.find('td:focus');
```

with this code

```
                active = element.find('td:focus').filter(function(){
                    var  i= -1;
                    var elem = this;
                    do {++i} while((elem=elem.previousSibling)!=null);
                    return !(activeOptions.disableColumnNumbers.indexOf(i) > -1);
                });
```

and then you will be able to declare your editor using disableColumnNumbers option like this

```
$("selector...").editableTableWidget({disableColumnNumbers: [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]});
```

good luck mate